# How to change state value without rebuilding the widget in Flutter using riverpod?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I am using **riverpod** package for state management in a Flutter app and I have a search sort provider as follows:

```
final searchSortStateProvider = StateProvider<SearchSort?>((ref) {   return SearchSort.relevance; });
```

But when the user searches again I want to reset the state of the search sort provider using the following code:

```
 ref.read(searchSortStateProvider.notifier).state = SearchSort.relevance;
```

It throws:

> "setState() or markNeedsBuild called during build"

Exception because I call it inside the init() method of the parent widget.

My question is how can I change the state of the provider without needing to rebuild the sort widget?

Comment: Can you please add your widget code?

Answer (score 1):

maybe you try `ref.refresh` or `ref.invalidate`/`ref.invalidateSelf()`?